# Usb camera usually disconnects and reconnect, but sometimes it disconnect and is not able to reconnect

Tags: usb

I have 4 USB camera connected, it usually keeps disconnecting reconnecting like [this](https://pastebin.com/8DhxasHP).

```
[ 1861.049925] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1861.050221] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1861.054222] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1861.058221] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1861.062221] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1861.066221] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1861.366095] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 1861.564743] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0515
[ 1861.564744] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=1
[ 1861.564745] usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0 Digital Camera
[ 1861.564746] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: USB2.0 Digital Camera
[ 1861.673998] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Digital Camera (05e3:0515)
[ 1861.720424] input: USB2.0 Digital Camera: USB2.0 D as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input23
```

But sometimes it disconnects and is not able to reconnect like [this](https://pastebin.com/KN277HeF).

```
usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 1860.978938] usb 1-3: config index 0 descriptor too short (expected 425, got 64)
[ 1860.978940] usb 1-3: config 1 has an invalid descriptor of length 27, skipping remainder of the config
[ 1860.978941] usb 1-3: config 1 has 1 interface, different from the descriptor's value: 2
[ 1860.978942] usb 1-3: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 has 0 endpoint descriptors, different from the interface descriptor's value: 1
[ 1860.998393] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0515
[ 1860.998395] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=1
[ 1860.998396] usb 1-3: Product: USB2.0 Digital Camera
[ 1860.998397] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: USB2.0 Digital Camera
[ 1861.049819] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Digital Camera (05e3:0515)
[ 1861.049823] uvcvideo: No valid video chain found.
```

When I execute `lsusb -t` I get following output :

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 17, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 15, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
```

What is happening here??

Comment: Bad cable?12345

Comment: Since I have 4 cameras connected, it is not fixed which camera will die,  it is just random. I've seen all of them die atleast once. So, I dont think its cable issue.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Are they connected to 4 USB ports on the same computer or to an external hub?  How long are the cables?

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE they are connected directly to the same computer.

Comment: Is it always #3?  If so you can try to exchange plugs and see if the problem moves with the plug.  If it is random, it is very unlikely that 4 lines are defective, so the internal USB might be broken, then you need to open the computer.

Comment: no, its random. I've tried exchanging ports etc. But its still random